# appending a fixed a number of div elements to a main div and the next set to another based on realtime results

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a facet based search for my webpage and Im using jquery for the front end part. Each search will return different set of facets. The content varies based on search terms. The number of contents is also nt a steady one. So my facet will look like this one for example.[image: facet jpg]

a set of individual terms wrapped inside a div element. So I the number of divs as u cn see is 7 for this one and I want to display the divs in such a way that only 4 divs are displayed in a single page and the next three in another. So Ive used jquery plugin named bxslider. Bt hw am I gonna break the set of 7 divs in to two pages?? The code that Ive used is

```
    noOfCol=Math.ceil(count4/8);
    noOfSlides=Math.ceil(noOfCol/4);
    //alert("Total number of slides " +noOfSlides);
    count4=0;
    var num=0;
    var num1=8;

    for(var count5=0;count5<noOfCol;++count5){
        var $newDiv = $('<div style="width:200px; height:160px; background-color:#000000; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; color:#ffffff;"></div>') ; 
        var $newDiv1 =$('<div style="float:left; width:900px; height:20px;"></div>') ;
        $("#test1").append($newDiv);

        for(count4=num; count4<num1; ++count4) {                        
            if(prsnArray[count4]==undefined) {
            } else {
                $newDiv.append('<input type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +prsnArray[count4].term + "&nbsp;&nbsp;(" + prsnArray[count4].count + ")" +'<br>');
            }
        }
        num=num+8
        num1=num1+8
    }

}
```

Comment: I want the  set of  contents ( 4 divs) in newDiv to newDiv1..

Comment: What exactly are the problem? Wrap newDiv and newDiv1 in a parent ex. bxDiv and use bxSlider on it?

Comment: I will xplain using abve example.. u cn see separate 7 divs in there.. I want to add only 4 divs inside a main div. and the remaining 3 divs to another div.. which should come out while clicking next button. How do i divide these 7 in to 4 and 3..also Ive nt usd wrap function til nw..

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/bMmLE/. Check out how the if-else statement is used in the for loop.
If the iteration "i" is over 4, then content is put in a different div.

I think this accomplishes what you're looking for if I understand your question correctly. Hope it points you in a good direction.

Comment: Sorrry.. This is nt the way.. This is jst appending to different divs.. sometimes we may need more than 3 or 4 divs...when the search result gives a result set of 12  or 16 facets.. we may have to creat div elements runtime and add to bx slider..

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but you're question was specific: "How do i divide these 7 in to 4 and 3". For a variable number of pages, pick how many divs you want in each page and use modulus operators in your for loop to create opening and closing page tags

Answer (score 0):

Im a little confused as to what you want, but i created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bMmLE/2/

It makes the div's for the slider automatic, from an set amount of max numbers, and adds it up.

```
count = 15; //random count
countPrDiv = 6; ///number of elements pr div
$parent = $('#sliderDiv'); //parent to add the divs too

for(var i = 0; count > i++;){
    if(i === 1) {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo($parent).addClass('max'+countPrDiv);
    } else if (i === countPrDiv) {
        countPrDiv = countPrDiv  + countPrDiv ;
        $('<div></div>').appendTo($parent).addClass('max'+countPrDiv);
    }

    $('.max'+countPrDiv).append('<p>'+i+'</p>');
}

$('#sliderDiv').bxSlider();
```